# How to preview and download Files in Community on button click using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, community-builder, customer-portal

I am trying to preview contentdocument record in community, I have used LWC for this, after login I have to show open a pop up on click of preview button I have to show contentdocument record as a preview.

I have tried many things but nothing is working.

can someone suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://www.salesforcetroop.com/file_preview_lwc
- https://gist.github.com/amitastreait/6d80c89ff95bb63bbd03659713e43d8d

Comment: Hi @TusharJadav I have tried above example, it is working salesforce lightning but it is not working in experience site.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this github repo https://github.com/annyhe/pdfViewer/tree/master with 99% complete solution on showing a preview of a PDF on the record page.

You just need to modify it to work on a Experience Cloud site.
Change the file showPdfRelatedToRecordId.js-meta.xml with the content below.

Then when you add the component to your site. Add `{!recordId}` to the input field "Record Id".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="showPdfRelatedToRecordId">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Show PDF Files Related To Record</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property label="Height in rem" name="heightInRem" type="Integer" default="40" />
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" label="Record Id" type="String" description="Set me to {!recordId}"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your Response, I have tried above code but receiving error message like, Invalid page